# Convert VHDL code to Verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I have to translate the following vhdl program to verilog:

```
ENTITY ascounter IS
  PORT (CLK :IN STD_LOGIC;
      QoutA, QoutB, QoutC, QoutD :OUT STD_LOGIC);
END ascounter;
ARCHITECTURE circuit OF ascounter IS
   SIGNAL CLKnot, QBnot, QCnot, QDnot, QA, QB, QC, QD, HIGH :STD_LOGIC;
   BEGIN
      HIGH<='1';
      CLKnot<=NOT CLK;
      QDnot<=NOT QD; 
      QCnot<=NOT QC;
      QBnot<=NOT QB;
      FFD: JKFF PORT MAP (J=>HIGH, K=>HIGH, CLK=>CLKnot, CLRN=>HIGH, PRN=>HIGH, Q=>QD);
      FFC: JKFF PORT MAP (J=>HIGH, K=>HIGH, CLK=>QDnot, CLRN=>HIGH, PRN=>HIGH, Q=>QC);
      FFB: JKFF PORT MAP (J=>HIGH, K=>HIGH, CLK=>QCnot, CLRN=>HIGH, PRN=>HIGH, Q=>QB);
      FFA: JKFF PORT MAP (J=>HIGH, K=>HIGH, CLK=>QBnot, CLRN=>HIGH, PRN=>HIGH, Q=>QA);
      QoutA<=QA;
      QoutB<=QB;
      QoutC<=QC;
      QoutD<=QD;
END circuit;
```

and I have done it:

```
  ...
  assign HIGH = 1'b1;
  assign CLKnot = (~CLK);
  assign QDnot = (~QD);
  assign QCnot = (~QC);
  assign QBnot = (~QB);

 flipflop_jk FFD(.J(HIGH), .K(HIGH), .CK(CLKnot), .CLN(HIGH), .PRN(HIGH), .Q(QD));

 flipflop_jk FFC(.J(HIGH), .K(HIGH), .CK(QDnot), .CLN(HIGH), .PRN(HIGH), .Q(QC));

 flipflop_jk FFB(.J(HIGH), .K(HIGH), .CK(QCnot), .CLN(HIGH), .PRN(HIGH), .Q(QB));

 flipflop_jk FFA(.J(HIGH), .K(HIGH), .CK(QBnot), .CLN(HIGH), .PRN(HIGH), .Q(QA));

 assign QoutA = QA;
 assign QoutB = QB;
 assign QoutC = QC;
 assign QoutD = QD;
```

I have used a jk flipflop:

```
always @(CK or PRN or CLN)
 begin
  if (PRN == 1'b0)
  begin
     Q <= 1'b1 ; 
  end
  else if (CLN == 1'b0)
  begin
     Q <= 1'b0 ; 
  end
  else if (CK == 1'b0)  
  begin
     if (J == 1'b1 & K == 1'b1)
     begin
        Q <= ~Q ; 
     end
     else if (J == 1'b1 & K == 1'b0)
     begin
        Q <= 1'b1 ; 
     end
     else if (J == 1'b0 & K == 1'b1)
     begin
        Q <= 1'b0 ; 
     end 
  end 
 end
```

When I try to run the simulation, I get something like this which is wrong, but I cannot understand where the mistake is.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You should add more info about what the problem is. _"...which is wrong"_ isn't enough.

Comment: Thought that the x value in the output makes it obvious what is wrong. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more appropriate to use edge sensitivity in the flipflop_jk definition, Also you have included an asynchronous clear signal, with a different value to your reset signal. My example shows this with a synchronous clear.

Your signal capture does not show your reset signal. I assume this is initially low then you take it high after time 0. To set Q to a known value.

```
module flipflop_jk(
  input      CK,
  input      PRN,
  input      CLN,
  input      J,
  input      K,
  output reg Q
);

always @(posedge CK or negedge PRN) begin
  if (PRN == 1'b0) begin
     Q <= 1'b1 ; 
  end
  else begin
    if (CLN == 1'b0) begin
      Q <= 1'b0 ; 
    end
    else if (J == 1'b1 & K == 1'b1) begin
      Q <= ~Q ; 
    end
    else if (J == 1'b1 & K == 1'b0) begin
      Q <= 1'b1 ; 
    end
    else if (J == 1'b0 & K == 1'b1) begin
      Q <= 1'b0 ; 
    end 
  end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have declared `Q` as a `reg` in your jk flipflop module.  By default in Verilog, a `reg` is initialized to `x`.  Since the `J`, `K`, `CLN` and `PRN` inputs to your jk flipflop are tied high (`1'b1`), the only statement which is executed is `Q <= ~Q ;` (when `CK` goes low).  `Q` remains unknown since the invert of `x` is still `x`.  You never set `Q` to a known value.